# angular bootstrap calender is not opening

Tags: angularjs

```
 $scope.datetimepicker=function(){
    console.log("in date time picker");
    $('#mypicker').datetimepicker();
    var reminder = $('#mypicker').val();
    console.log(reminder);
}
```

Above is controller code.
It is taking time from input and print in console

```
<!------------------------- angular  ---------------------------->

 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.6/angular.js">
</script>

<script type="text/javascript"
src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/1.0.3/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>

<script
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

 <script
src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

 <script 
src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.8/angular-sanitize.js"></script>

 <script type="text/javascript"  src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/2.5.0/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js"></script>


<script
src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.10.6/moment.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="node_modules/angular-bootstrap-datetimepicker/src/js/datetimepicker.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="node_modules/angular-bootstrap-datetimepicker/src/js/datetimepicker.templates.js"></script>
    <script
src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.37/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
```

above are scripts included

```
below is html code:     
 <div class="col-md-6">
  <div class="input-group date" id="endTime" data-
  datetimepicker="datetimepicker" ng-click="datetimepicker()" ng-
 model="stat.endTime" data-date-format="MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm A/PM" >
    <input id="mypicker" class="form-control" type="text" 
  placeholder="Remainder date"/>
    <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-
calendar"></span>
   </span>
   </div>
  </div>
```

Calender is not opening.

When I click on input field current time is displayed but without opening calender

Comment: date time picker is working out side of ng-repeat,how to apply inside ng repeat